# LookAt is centering at feet of player

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I use `LookAt` the camera seems to look at the targets feet. I would like the target to be closer to the bottom of the screen. (e.g. look at the head instead).

Code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject player;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0,2.0f,-4.0f);
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform.position);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so the camera stop centering at the feet?

Comment: It looks like the pivot point of your player is the feet. Is this true?

Comment: I don't know what that means. Lol. I'm guessing I can just set the Y transform property to += 4.0f or something after the LookAt?

Comment: If you don't know pivot point is, do a quick research about it. Yes, you can increase the Y after the lookAt. You can also increase the y value of `player.transform.position` before the lookAt. `transform.LookAt(player.transform.position + new Vector3(0,4.0f,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an empty game object as a child of the player, and then adjusted the position of that. Then in my script I set it to look at that empty object instead of the player. This gives me full control of what position the camera looks at on the player.